# Save a curdoc with Bokeh

Tags: bokeh

I'm beginner on Bokeh, I'd like to know if it's possible to save a `curdoc()` in an HTML file? We can take as an example my little test below :

```
import numpy as np from bokeh.palettes
import RdYlGn11 as palette from bokeh.plotting
import figure from bokeh.layouts
import row, widgetbox from bokeh.models
import ColumnDataSource from bokeh.models.widgets
import Slider, TextInput, Select from bokeh.io
import curdoc, output_file, save, set_curdoc
x = np.array([-10., -8., -7., -2., 0., 1., 2., 5., 7., 9.])
y = np.array([-15., -12., -9., -5., 1., 4., 6., 7., 9., 12.])
def f(x, y, a, b):
  return a * x + b * y
z = f(x, y, -2, 3.2)
colors = np.array(palette)
task_color = np.arange(-10, 10, 10)
source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(X = x, Y = y, Z = z, color = colors[task_color.searchsorted(z)]))
plot = figure(plot_height = 800, plot_width = 800)
plot.circle("X", "Y", size = 10, line_color = "color", fill_color = "color", source = source)
plot.text("X", "Y", text = "Z", source = source)
A = Slider(title = "First coefficient", value = -2., start = -10, end = 10, step = 1.)
B = Slider(title = "Second coefficient", value = 3.2, start = 0., end = 5., step = 0.1)
def update_data(attrname, ols, new):
  a = A.value
b = B.value
x = np.array([-10., -8., -7., -2., 0., 1., 2., 5., 7., 9.])
y = np.array([-15., -12., -9., -5., 1., 4., 6., 7., 9., 12.])
z = f(x, y, a, b)
source.data = dict(X = x, Y = y, Z = z, color = colors[task_color.searchsorted(z)])
for w in [A, B]:
  w.on_change('value', update_data)
inputs = widgetbox(A, B)
curdoc().add_root(row(inputs, plot))
curdoc().title = "My test"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a Bokeh *application* In order to function, it cannot be saved, it must be *executed* by a Bokeh server. i.e. if your code above is in a file `app.py`, then the only way to get it function and perform is to run

```
bokeh serve --show app.py
```

at your command line. There is no way to "save" it such that it will run *without* a Bokeh Server. There are other ways besides scripts to specify and build applications, but to operate, they all must be run inside Bokeh serve. See:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html

Alernatively, if you don't need to execute *real, actual Python code* in your callbacks, you can have many highly interactive standalone (i.e. no Bokeh server) plots with things like `CustomJS` callbacks. See:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-model-property-events